# React router params not working for getting id

Tags: reactjs

From last couple of days I was finding a solution for this problem. What is happening here is I want dynamic link. You can see below here:

```
<Route  path="edit/:id" component={EditExpense} />
```

But when I go to `/edit/12`, I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/edit/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED




import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 
'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
import AddExpense from '../components/AddExpense'
import EditExpense from '../components/EditExpense'
import Help from '../components/Help'
import PageNotFound from '../components/PageNotFound'

export default function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route  path="/" component={Dashboard}  exact />
                <Route  path="/create" component={AddExpense} />
                <Route  path="edit/:id" component={EditExpense} />
                <Route  path="/help" component={Help} />
                <Route  component={PageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try with `path="/edit/:id"` instead of `path="edit/:id"`

Comment: Is ```EditExpense``` successfully shown?

Comment: @Hassan Imam. i have tried that ' path="/edit/:id"' but not working

Comment: @isecheukfung01. No it's not showing the EditExpense component

Comment: I think I've typically seen questions related to this issue pop up when you've hosted your react app out on a server. React apps are *technically* Single Page Apps, so the root routes all work and the app is manipulating the address bar. But if you try to navigate directly to a nested route, you are requesting a page from that physical directory on the server, and since it doesn't exist you get this error. The solution typically involves creating/editing the `.htaccess` file to handle nested paths and redirect users back to the path where your app is served up.